Cannot connect to MySQL database when I deploy my app on python even with a valid URL_DATABASE
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

URL_DATABASE = 'mysql+pymysql://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@localhost:3306/travelsyncapi'

engine = create_engine(URL_DATABASE)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

My fastapi app is supposed to connect to an sql schema I created called travelsyncapi and should be able to post information to it but when i try to deploy it it crashes and throws this error:
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
I expected it to connect to the database and for the fastapi page to show up on my browser, with the different API endpoints I created, from where I could send in information to the endpoint. Checked to make sure the ports on the url and the mysql instance were the same, made sure mysql server was running. still dont know whats wrong. not sure where to go from here.

Unfortunately, we cannot tell you why you get connection refused error beyond the standard server is not running, server is running but listens on a different port, or something else is blocking the connection - all these are listed as answers to the duplicate question multiple times.
